# fx:deploy with nativeBundles = image does not let me run the executable from folder containing special characters

Tags: javafx, deployment, ant

On windows: I create a build with ant from IntelliJ and that when run from folder called "š" does not run anything. When I run directly the jar everything works fine.

On mac: The executable .app build can be run but System.getProperty("user.dir") returns the path wrongly (the special chars are wrong), again if the jar is run directly, the path is alright.

```
<fx:application id="SId" name="s" mainClass="packageName"/>
      <fx:jar destfile="${artifact.temp.output.mainJar}/S.jar">
      <fx:application refid="SId"/>
      <fileset dir="${artifact.temp.output.mainJar}" excludes="**/*.jar"/>
      <fx:resources>
          <fx:fileset dir="${artifact.temp.output.mainJar}" includes="**/*.jar" />
      </fx:resources>
      <fx:platform javafx="2.1+">
          <fx:property name="file.encoding" value="UTF-8"/>
      </fx:platform>
    <manifest/>
  </fx:jar>

  <fx:deploy width="600" height="400" updatemode="background" outdir="${artifact.temp.output.mainJar}/deploy" outfile="S" nativeBundles="image">
      <fx:application refid="SId"/>
      <fx:resources>
          <fx:fileset dir="${artifact.temp.output.mainJar}" includes="**/*.jar"/>
      </fx:resources>
      <fx:info>
      <fx:icon href="${basedir}/build_scripts/${iconFileName}" />
      </fx:info>
      <fx:platform javafx="2.1+">
          <fx:property name="file.encoding" value="UTF-8"/>
      </fx:platform>
  </fx:deploy>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known problem, which already got reported one the JDK.

[JDK-8133034 launcher crashes if started with non english arguments](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8133034)

[JDK-8138642 Generated bundle is not executable when main class contains unicode](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8138642)

Since this is a general problem with the native executables, and both issues being open for that long (because it involves C++ and unicode-problems), there is no quick solution for this.

Funny part: I was checking for this today as some issue-cleanup on the javafx-maven-plugin project: https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin/issues/209